# Maximum of $e^{-x} \sin(x)$, $x \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

What is the maximum of $e^{-x} \sin(x)$ for $x \geq 0$? Is there a closed-form solution? If not, what is a good approximation $y$ such that $\text{max}_{x\geq 0}e^{-x} \sin(x) \leq y$?

Comment: $e^{-\pi/4}/\sqrt2$. Did you take the derivative?

Comment: You are right. That was easy.

Comment: Just as a curiosity, how do you get to $x = e^{-\pi/4} / \sqrt{2}$ from the derivative function: $g(x) = e^{-x}(\cos(x) - \sin(x))$?

Comment: You solve $g(x)=0$ for $x$.